# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A' plot

Tags: pandas, string, type-conversion

I am experiencing an issue with a plot. I get the error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'

and the  column I am targeting has ratings A, B, C, D, E, F, G.

I expect the line to look as the one attached in the image.

```py
def plot_WoE(df_WoE, r_x_axis = 0):
    x = np.array(df_WoE.iloc[: , 0].astype(str))
    y =df_WoE['WoE']
    plt.figure(figsize = (18,6))
    plt.plot(x,y, marker = 'o', linestyle = '--', color = 'k')
    plt.xlabel(df_WoE.columns[0])
    plt.ylabel('Weight of Evidence')
    plt.title(str('Weight of Evidence by '+ df_WoE.columns[0]))
    plt.xticks(rotation = r_x_axis)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! A few things: your image didn't attach, and to help answer your question, we need to be able to see what df_WoE looks like. Read [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Derek, I was unable to attach an image since I am new here, can you reccomend a way toshare the image? I appreciate your help

Comment: Can you edit your question, and on top of the sample suggested by Derek, can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: What is the output from df_WoE? What is the type of each column? Post the full traceback of the error message too, as it will tell us which line(s) are problematic (although here it's probably x = np.array(df_WoE.iloc[: , 0].astype(str)) that is causing problems)